# UITabBarController icons changing height on touch

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, uiedgeinsets

I have an issue with `UITabBarController`, the icons are changing size if I keep my finger on them and drag up or down, they are losing height by my dragging action, how can I stop that?

Here is my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   .................

    vc_friends.tabBarItem.imageInsets   = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    vc_topCharts.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    vc_newsfeed.tabBarItem.imageInsets  = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    vc_myProfile.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)
    vc_pools.tabBarItem.imageInsets     = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0)

    self.viewControllers = [vc_friends,vc_topCharts,vc_newsfeed,vc_pools,vc_myProfile]

    self.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: correctly displayed tab bar item]

...and this if I click on it and keep my finger on it and move my finger up or down:

[image: distorted tab bar item]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue when your negative value is not the opposite of the positive value in the other direction. Change your insets to this:

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
```